# php creating a css stylesheet list from directory

Tags: php, html, css

Im trying to read css files from a directory and create the respective html markup, like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

### PHP

```
 $css_dir = 'application/resources/css';

$fp = opendir($css_dir);
while ($file = readdir($fp)) 
{
if (strpos($file, '.css',1))
$results[] = $this->base.'/'.$file;                 
}
closedir($fp);

print_r($results);
```

this works correctly creating an array with results like `[1] => Directory/name.css` which is fine but if I change the results line to something like

```
$results[] = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="'.$this->base.'/'.$file.'">';
```

I get am empty array, the problem is with the '<' '>' symbols is there no way to do this in one go without having to then do a foreach through the results array?

Comment: Be aware - and this is just a warning - that if you plan on making this a public-facing application, it is very insecure to blindly load files in a directory. Good luck

Comment: What? Did you check the source code, since `<link ..>` probably won't show on the screen - but nevertheless it should work. However, it can be simplified by using `glob`

Comment: @David can you explain how? A user will not be able to place any files into that directory without root access.

Comment: Try `echo '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($results, true)) . '</pre>';` to see the results literally.

Comment: @Barmar thanks this is just what I needed, i forgot link will just get rendered and won't show up on the print_r.

Comment: could someone explain how this is insecure?

Comment: @Edward it is insecure to trust everyone on the interweb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<` and `>` use `&lt;` and `&gt;` accordingly, or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

**Improvement in your functional code**

```
 /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

 /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)